# Show two models (Images and Treatments) in one table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models that belong to patient Images and Treatments. On the show patients page i would like to show both in one table. So far i have a treatments table:

```
<% @treatments.each do |f| %>
<tr class="<%= category_table_row_class(f.category) %>">
<td> <%= f.category.try(:text) %></td>
<td> <% if f.content[0..5] == 'data:i' %>
     <%= image_tag f.content %>
     <% else %>
     <%= f.content %> 
     <% end %> </td>
<td><%= f.date %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

And the images table:

```
<%= @images.each do |f| %>
<td><%= image_tag(f.thumb) %></td>
<% end %>
```

How can i merge the two tables? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be looking at Single Table Inheritance.